# Solaris 11 smbfs mount utility is failing to mount SMB2.0 onward windows shares

Tags: solaris, smb

We are using smbfs mount utility in solaris 11 to mount windows SMB2 share but failure was reported as below:

command(executed with root):

```
sudo mount -F smbfs -o user=administrator,uid=oracle //win-t370714v98p/TestMnt /mnt/TestMnt
```

explanation:

```
//win-t370714v98p/TestMnt - windows SMB2.0 share
/mnt/TestMnt - local mountpoint on solaris11 server

Error: /usr/lib/fs/smbfs/mount: //win-t370714v98p: login failed: syserr = Connection reset by peer
```

For SMb1.0 share smbfs mount utility is able to perform ount successfully but fails for SMB2.0 onward shareds.
Does solaris11 smbfs mount supports on SMB2.0?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.  The maximum protocol version for the client side is SMB1.0, as documented in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37852/smb-5.html.